# Chrome cannot download files from network path

Tags: google-chrome, network-shares, download

I am trying to download a file from network path and Chrome Dev Tools shows 200 for the request but the file does not download (nothing happens on the webpage). When I tried to open the link in new tab it says about:blank#blocked. The file downloads fine in IE/Edge. I think there is a Chrome setting somewhere which I have to disable. I have enabled Flash, 'Safe Browsing' and 'Popup and redirect' options still no luck. Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I could fix it with an extension from chrome webstore "Enable local file links" https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-local-file-links/nikfmfgobenbhmocjaaboihbeocackld